# how to highlight pdf document word by term use php?

Tags: javascript, php, highlight

I am beginner in Php. I have to highlight text inside Pdf using php native just look like mark.js but mark.js just give highlight html document. Is it possible?. i have search all forum in google and i dont have the answer for my question. Please suggest me any solutions.

Comment: If you post your code which you already tried SO community will help to get what you want.

Comment: i dont have the code for this, i just finish convert doc file into pdf use openoffice and now i want to give highlight for word inside pdf

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Before posting a question, it is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have answer my question just add #search= and the word you want to find insert the pdf document and it automatic show the word with highlight
example :
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html#search=Type

but now i have a new problem 
can i change the color of highlight with another color?